# Event when Tab Bar Item is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've setup a Tab Bar with some tabs into my app. I've a view controller among other view controllers (managed by this TabBarController) who run some process when init method is called. And it seems the init method is triggerred one time so I don't know how to update the related view content. Any idea where (in which method) I can run this process?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     // ...
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     // ...
}
```

Comment: In some situations the viewDidAppear would have to be "reset" if it has already been loaded..
[mainView addSubview:myView.view];  
[myView viewDidAppear:NO];  

Should not be needed in most cases though.

Answer (score 2):

To update the view every time it appears just use:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

When/how often exactly do you want update your view? Which elements?

Comment: well I'm not sure exactly how often...but no more than 100 items I think so

Comment: so, do you mean everytime one goes away from the tab and then returns? or what should trigger the reloading?